# Is it possible to add an extra column with a specific value on SpatiaLite using ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr, spatialite

Let's say I have a `SpatiaLite` database with a column called `source` where I have different kinds of values like the following

```
source
value1
value1
value1
value2
value2
```

Let's also say that outside the database I have two variables:

```
value1: specification1
value2: specification2
```

I'd like to insert this data on my SpatiaLite database in a way that I'll create a new column on it and distribute those variable values on the database. Something like the following:

```
source newcolumn
value1 specification1
value1 specification1
value1 specification1
value2 specification2
value2 specification2
```

Is it possible? Can I continually add new values to a SpatiaLite database from external parameters using `ogr2ogr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With ogr2ogr**:

You can avoid creating a new output file or append a new table to existing datasource, for database, as mentioned in the comments

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f GPKG out.gpkg -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT *, CASE WHEN source = 'value1' THEN 'specification1' WHEN source = 'value2' THEN 'specification2' ELSE '' END newcolumn1 FROM your_table_name;" yourfile.sqlite
```

**Using ogrinfo**

You mutate existing table and do not create a new table, only add a new column

Create `newcolumn` by running the following only once

```bsh
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD COLUMN newcolumn TEXT;" yourfile.sqlite
```

Then each time you want to update the column

```bsh
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE your_table_name SET newcolumn= CASE WHEN source = 'value1' THEN 'specification1' WHEN source = 'value2' THEN 'specification2' ELSE '' END;" yourfile.sqlite
```

**Alternative** (only idea, did not implemented here)

You could also join `your_table_name` with another table (as mentioned in [GDAL doc about "SQL SQLite dialect"](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#select-statement)) to make the update instead of doing it by editing manually the SQL statement each time a new rule may appear

Comment: Just as a curiosity, why are you generating a GPKG package on your first sample? Is it because `ogr2ogr` always needs to generate an output file?

Comment: Right, ogr2ogr creates always a new layer. Adding a new table into existing SQLite db is possible. In that case the command needs to include options `-f SQLite -append -update -nln new_layer_name`.