# How do I add a new column to a GPKG file using ogrinfo?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, geopackage, ogrinfo

I create an example file, `example.gpkg` using Python:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(dict(
        geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0]), shapely.geometry.Point([1, 1])],
        col0=["a","b"]))

gdf.to_file("example.gpkg",driver="GPKG")
```

I would like to add another property to each geometry using [`ogrinfo`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html). To do this, I try creating another column, `col1` & try setting the `col1` value of each geometry to `1234` as an example. ([This thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402593/191643) explains how to do this on a SpatiaLite database using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) - now I'm working with a GPKG file.) I do:

```
sql="
ALTER TABLE example ADD COLUMN col1 INTEGER;
UPDATE example SET col1=1234;
"

ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "${sql}" example.gpkg
```

However, when I read back the GPKG into a GeoDataFrame:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("example.gpkg")
```

and `print(gdf)`, I get:

```
  col0  col1                 geometry
0    a   NaN  POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
1    b   NaN  POINT (1.00000 1.00000)
```

ie all the `col1` values are `NaN`, instead of `1234`, so this approach failed.

**How do I add a new column to a GPKG file using `ogrinfo`?**

Comment: I believe that ogrinfo can send only one SQL statement. Run ogrinfo separately for ALTER TABLE and for UPDATE.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Would you like to add that as an answer? If you know documentation where one could have learnt this, it would be awesome to reference that.

Comment: Maybe not as explicit as can be, but in the documentation of [ogrinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html#cmdoption-ogrinfo-sql) it is stated like this: `Execute the indicated SQL statement and return the result.` SQL statement is singular, so you can only run one SQL statement at a time.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to accomplish, but just for info: SQLite also supports specyfing a default value for a column, so you can also do the following: `ALTER TABLE example ADD COLUMN col1 INTEGER DEFAULT 1234`. This will fill up all rows automatically with 1234, but if you insert new rows without specifying a value for column col1 it will also automatically get 1234 as value.

Comment: The `-sql` option in ogr2ogr or ogrinfo is basically launching the ExecuteSQL() https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALDataset.html#a5b65948b1e15fa63e96c0640eb6c5d7c function for the datastore. Feel free to write the answer yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to split up the query to 2 SQL statements, as `ogrinfo` can send 1 SQL statement at a time.

```
sql0="ALTER TABLE example ADD COLUMN col1 INTEGER;"
sql1="UPDATE example SET col1=1234;"

ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "${sql0}" example.gpkg
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "${sql1}" example.gpkg
```