# How do I set the result of a SELECT query equal to a new column in a GPKG file using ogrinfo?

Tags: gdal, sql, ogrinfo

This thread: [How do I add a new column to a GPKG file using ogrinfo?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471742/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-gpkg-file-using-ogrinfo) explains how to add a new column to a GPKG file and set all rows in it to a specific constant value. Here, I would like to add a new column to a GPKG file and set it equal to the result of a SELECT query.

Create mock GPKG file:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(dict(
        geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0]), shapely.geometry.Point([1, 1])],
        col0=["a","b"]))

gdf.to_file("example.gpkg",driver="GPKG")
```

An attempt to create and populate a new column:

```
sql0="ALTER TABLE example ADD COLUMN col1 TEXT;"
sql1="UPDATE example SET col1=(SELECT CONCAT(col0,col0) FROM example);"

ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "${sql0}" example.gpkg
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "${sql1}" example.gpkg
```

I used `CONCAT(col0,col0)` as an example. I am interested in a general answer, ie how can  I set `col1` equal to the result of `SELECT SOME_FUNCTION(some_columns) FROM table`.

The resulting GPKG file has these columns (via `print(gpd.read_file("example.gpkg"))`):

```
  col0 col1                 geometry
0    a   aa  POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
1    b   aa  POINT (1.00000 1.00000)
```

I expected `col1` to have `aa` & `bb`. In other words, expected result is:

```
  col0 col1                 geometry
0    a   aa  POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
1    b   bb  POINT (1.00000 1.00000)
```

To check the sql query, I do:

```
ogrinfo example.gpkg -sql "SELECT CONCAT(col0,col0) FROM example"
```

which returns:

```
INFO: Open of `example.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 2
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
CONCAT(col0,col0): String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  CONCAT(col0,col0) (String) = aa

OGRFeature(SELECT):1
  CONCAT(col0,col0) (String) = bb
```

As expected, `aa` and `bb` shows up. I want both of them to show up in the newly created `col1` too.

**How do I set the result of a SELECT query equal to a new column in a GPKG file using ogrinfo?**

---

`ogrinfo --version` returns: `GDAL 3.8.3, released 2024/01/04`

Comment: You need to make sure that the `SELECT` sub-query that you perform returns *a **single**, well referenced value only* - what you are seeing in your example is due to the query creating the *same* result set in the `SELECT` for each row, and the `UPDATE` always assigning the first found row (in pseudo-deterministic order)! In your example, if the new columns value source is the same table, you can simply `UPDATE table SET new_col = CONCAT(table.other_col_1, table.other_col_2);`

Comment: This worked, thanks. Would you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: Just for information, because I frequently edit geopackages as well from python, [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/) has some helper functions for this kind of operations: [geofileops.add_column](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.add_column.html#geofileops.add_column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)**

```
sql0="ALTER TABLE example ADD COLUMN col1 TEXT;"
sql1="UPDATE example SET col1 =  CONCAT(col0, col0);"

ogrinfo -sql "${sql0}" example.gpkg
ogrinfo -sql "${sql1}" example.gpkg
```

---

**Using [`geofileops`](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)**

```
import geofileops

geofileops.add_column(
    "example.gpkg", name="col1", type="TEXT", expression="CONCAT(col0, col0);"
)
```

Interestingly, `geofileops` is around 10 times faster in this specific example. Promising!

Comment: For information, geofileops also uses gdal under the hood for this functionality, so it is very similar what is happening. What is different is that when using ogrinfo, a new process is being created for each statement, which is relatively expensive. So, I expect that if your update statement is very quick, the overhead of starting the processes will be very significant as in your test. If you do an update that takes a lot of time (many seconds) the relative time difference will probably be a lot smaller.